# Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

This is my code where I am getting error "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

```
var objectData = new object[colRindas.Count, 4];
     int i = 0;
     foreach (DeArtIzm izm in colRindas)
     {
         objectData[i, 1] = izm.ArtCode;
         objectData[i, 2] = izm.ArtName;
         objectData[i, 3] = izm.Price;
         objectData[i, 4] = izm.RefPrice;
         i++;//Place where I get that error
     }
```

What seems to be the problem hare, cause I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Arrays are 0-indexed instead of one.

```
foreach (DeArtIzm izm in colRindas)
     {
         objectData[i, 0] = izm.ArtCode;
         objectData[i, 1] = izm.ArtName;
         objectData[i, 2] = izm.Price;
         objectData[i, 3] = izm.RefPrice;
         i++;//Place where I get that error
     }
```

Comment: Also, he should reset his debugger symbols.  Clean the solution (ensure the .pdb file is deleted).  Out of synch symbols would explain why the exception was thrown on `i++`

Answer (score 0):

in C#, Arrays are Zero-based by default (i.e. The first element has the index 0).

So you need to start with `objectData[i, 0]`, and end with `objectData[i, 3]`.